# Python multiprocessing to process a large xml file

Tags: python, xml, multithreading, multiprocessing, chunking

My current design

[image: Single processing]

From the large xml, loop through each element, then flatten it, and save it into multiple json file. In the `Loop each element` process took very long time.

What I want to achieve is

[image: Multi processing]

Split it before the loop. Possible to achieve?

**P/S: the flatten process is like**

```
<root>
    <aaa>
        <bbb>
            <ccc>
                Foo
            </ccc>
        </bbb>
        <xxx>
            Bar
        </xxx>
    </aaa>
    <aaa>
        <bbb>
            <ccc>
                Alice
            </ccc>
        </bbb>
        <xxx>
            Bob
        </xxx>
    </aaa>
</root>
```

into

```
[
    {
        "aaa_bbb_ccc": "Foo",
        "aaa_xxx": "Bar"
    },
    {
        "aaa_bbb_ccc": "Alice",
        "aaa_xxx": "Bob"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could work with threadpools or processes to be faster. Threads would easy life for others working on the same server. If you are alone you could work with processes.